# CodeIgniter renaming image to be the next id in db table

Tags: image, codeigniter

I'm brand new to codeigniter and am trying to rename my image to be the next auto incremented number in the table.

I was looking into using

```
$id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

But am still unsure how to add 1 to that value and use it for my file name.  I've got image resizing all set just need to rename and I'm set.

Any help would be much appreciated!!!  Thanks so much!

Controller:

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);


        if ( !$this->upload->do_upload() )
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            redirect('index.php/success');
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $this->resize($data['upload_data']['full_path'], $data['upload_data']['file_name']);
            redirect('index.php/success');
            echo $img;

        }

        // Update Record to save filename
    }

    function resize($path, $file){

        $config['image_library']= 'gd2';
        $config['source_image']= $path;
        $config['create_thumb']= TRUE;
        $config['maintain_ration']= TRUE;
        $config['width']= 320;
        $config['height']= 196;
        $config['new_image']='./uploads/'.$file;

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();


    }
```

Comment: _Its weird to do this but anyway_, set your id in table to AU (auto increment) and like magic it is auto incrementing itself ;)

Comment: I apologize if my issue isn't clear.  I have my auto increment set up fine in my DB.  I want to rename my uploaded file to be the number of the next row ID.  So if I'm uploading image.jpg - and the next id in my db is 10, I want my image to be renamed to 10.jpg.

Answer (score 0):

Get the last number of the id column which you have set to auto increment.You can use sql Max() function to that.Then simply add a 1 to that and use it for the image renaming.That's it!!!